# What is the meaning of the "E" in the part number of Texas Instrument's CD4000 series?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, cmos, texas-instruments

Most CD4xxx chips come with a part number of CD4xxxBE or CD4xxxUBE.

[Official documentation](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa142a/sboa142a.pdf) tells you that B and UB stand for buffered and unbuffered outputs respectively, and mentions that the last letter should indicate package designation and take values of F, K or D, but there's no mention of what the E at the end stands for.

Most of the chips I buy on the market have that last E, but what does it mean?

Comment: Just packaging. "B" is PDIP, "F" is CDIP, "M" is SOIC, and "PW" is TSSOP, for example. I believe it's very easy to find this information in [some chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRqEh.png) of most any datasheet. I never thought much about it. Just observed the rules, so to speak. But there it is. Not difficult to parse out. Apparently, you like PDIPs. I prefer CDIP. But they are more expensive, too. ;)

Comment: Could be a general code for temperature grade.  For instance, Microchip parts which end in an "I" are industrial-temp-rated.

Comment: It should also be said that the space military and enchanced list from Texas Instruments that is behind the "Official Documentation" list by no means is the "proper" source of data for naming nomenclature for 40xx series circuits, it's rather a specialized list of documentation for a niche subset of components. It's better to - as suggested by the already supplied answers - to look into a specific part data sheet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking at a catalog that only cares about the ceramic versions, so it only lists the suffixes for the ceramic versions.

Looking at a [Harris (pre-TI) datasheet](https://www.datasheetbank.com/datasheet-download/887222/1/Harris/CD4000) because it's a nice easy read:

> The CD4000UB, CD4001UB, CD4002UB, and CD4025UB types are supplied in 14-lead hermetic dual-in-line ceramic packages (D and F suffixes), 14-lead dual-in-line plastic packages (E suffix), 14-lead ceramic flat packages (K suffix), and in chip form (H suffix).

D, F, and K agree with the PDF you linked, and E is plastic DIP.

Answer (score 3):

Any old 4000 series [TI data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4001b.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1691954875164&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fcd4001b) provides this packaging information at the end: -

[image]

- E is for PDIP
- F is for CDIP
- M is for SOIC
- etc..

Answer (score 3):

The [CD4001 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4001ub.pdf) says "14-lead dual-in-line plastic packages (E suffix)" and the [CD4009 dtatasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4010b.pdf) says "16-lead dual-in-line plastic packages (E suffix)", on the first page.

The E seems to mean "plastic DIP".